# How to check whether the reindex working or not in Magento?

Tags: magento2, reindex

I have seen the Index Management of our site via admin panel **System**->**Index Management**. While checking, some of the indexes haven't updated. In this case, I'm not sure whether the index is working or not.

Please see the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Could anyone please guide me on how to check the reindex status?

Comment: Your mode is "update on save". so save a category and see if its getting updated. Or you can try changing mode to "update by schedule" and setup a cron for the updation.

Comment: The thing is when I save a category, it's updating but in the index management, the indexer update date is not updated to the latest date.

Comment: Have you tried running reindex from terminal  php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three steps to schedule index cronjobs

1. In **store -> Configuration**
2. Through **shell**
3. In `crontab.xml`

shell crontab will run magento cron for every 1 minute, it will check you `Store->Config` setting, and after that it will go to the `crontab.xml` to check cron scheduling.

So if you want to run using update and save, then you will need to schedule cron(Shell) for every 1 minute, and also 1 minute in configuration.

You don't need to worry about crontab.xml because it has the best scheduling in default according to Magento default settings.

Now check in store -> Configuration

Go to

> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System

in **Cron (Scheduled Tasks)** check **Cron configuration options for group: index** and verify if **General Scheduling Every** is set to **1**

After that, you will need to check cron scheduling on shell
`crontab -e` (for ubuntu).
Cron scheduling should be like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/var/log/magent$
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/update/cron.php >> /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

**Note: Path should be set according to your project**

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for short and detailed information. I have checked all the points you have mentioned and see that all are set correctly. However, in the admin panel, the date is not updated for some of the indexers at index Management. Yes, that's not big deal after I have known the cron is working fine. But I would like to know why the date is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. +1 for that :)

Comment: You deserve it :) I have checked and see the Schedule Status isn't showing any error against an index. What does it mean?

Comment: Did you check on frontend, if data is appearing what you have edit, then cron is working fine and it is not updating the date, that wont be an issue then

Comment: Yes, the changes are reflecting on the frontend. So now I concluded that the cron is working fine for our site. Thank you very much for all your information.

Comment: I have also checked on my website 2.2 EE. I have updated product title and it is reflected on frontend, but time of index is still the old one. I think this is magento issue, it is not updated when we set update on save, and if we run index using script it will update it's datetime.

Comment: Yes, same here. So that it may Magento issue as you said.

Answer (score 6):

You can check via command line:

```
php bin/magento i:status
```

Comment: I have checked the reindex status via command, it shows all the indexes are ready but my question if you see the attached screenshot the date is not updated in the Index Management at admin panel. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @Narendra, good approach you provided to check cron status. +1 for that

Answer (score 5):

Indexers can be managed/updated by two following ways.

1. **Update on Save**: This runs every time when ever you are making any changes to the particular field & save it. viz. When a customer is buying a product stock Index is get reindexed, When you are making any changes into the product price product price indexer is get reindexed. It works similarly for other indexers also.
2. **Update By Schedule**: It is running based on the cron set in your Magento.

Here in your settings your **Indexer update Action Mode** is set on **Update on Save** & since you haven't made any changes from long time into Product Categories & into the Product Price/Cart Price rule So it is not showing any update into it. As of you will create any cart rule or you will make any changes to the product category it will run the relevant indexers & then you can see the updates into that particular indexer.

If you want to run the indexers on the basis of cron schedule change the **Action** drop-down value to **Update By Schedule** & click on the submit. You can set these indexers cron from Below location.

> - Go to Admin > STORES > Settings > Configuration.
> - Go to Advanced > System > Cron (Schedule Task)
> - Change the values as per your requirement in **Cron configuration options for group: index**
> - Save the changes & flush the cache.

Answer (score 5):

You have enabled **Update on Save**, so the reindex will occur in realtime whenever a change is made in the admin. So you might not have done any changes for that indexers product category and catalog rules, so that you are seeing the last updated date(i.e.) reindex has occurred when you made changes to those indexers in December and March.

So if you enable the reindex to **Update on Schedule** , the reindex will occur through cron job regularly.