# Is going to reindex automatically?

Tags: magento2, indexer, magento-cron

If I build a module with a indexer, is Magento going to run the reindex automatically each night or do I need to create a cronjob for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether the reindex working or not in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269624/how-to-check-whether-the-reindex-working-or-not-in-magento)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the reindex happen automatically, you need to set a cronjob for that. Please refer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269624/how-to-check-whether-the-reindex-working-or-not-in-magento) for detailed explanations:

Answer (score 0):

Automatic re-indexing always require a active Cronjob