# Issue with Index Management

Tags: magento2, product, indexing, crontab, magento-cron

I am running bin/magento indexer:reindex command for indexing.
In admin panel Systems->Index Management
Updated column shows the updated indexing date for all except ' Product Categories ' and 'Product Price'.

[image]

How to resolve this?

Also i want to know how to set up cron for indexing if i choosed 'Update by schedule'

Comment: Did you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue. When index updated using **"Update on Save"** this will not set last updated date. Whereas if you run indexing manually then it will set last updated date.

Just make sure you have enabled magento cronjobs by this command:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

For detail of Magento indexing you can follow my answer here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269629/31910

Comment: What to do if i want to run indexing in every 5 mins and not 1 min

Comment: For every 5 minutes you need to update `crontab.xml` file, the file location would depend on your index type. You can find it in relevant module. You can search on codebase to get location of `crontab.xml` if it is in core module, then you would need to override it

Comment: ..........Yes, this issue is resolved with the solution you provide. thank you

Comment: That's great, welcome :) Please vote on answer and mark it correct if it is helpful to you, so that it would be helpful for others in future

Comment: If i do Update on save again, it is showing previous date for some indexer like May and june. @Shoaib Munir

Comment: If you set "Update on Save" then ignore last updated date, it's magento issue it will to update last index date, it only stores last updated date if you set it on "Update on schedule" or manually update index

Answer (score 1):

First reset that two indexer and run indexer for that two index.

Run below command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category
> catalog_product_price
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category
> catalog_product_price
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

**For set up cron:**

Install the cronjob by this command.

> php bin/magento cron:install [--force]

Refer the link for more information:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Hope it help.

Comment: This worked for catalog_product_category but not for 'Catalog product rule' The time is still not updated

Comment: You can run the command 
(1) php bin/magento indexer:reset

(2) php bin/magento indexer:reindex